# Polars custom function returning multiple features

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm evaluating `polars` for timeseries feature extraction - replicating for example the functionality of libraries such as `tsfresh`.

I have the basics working really well, i.e. using `dynamic grouping` to create windows and most of the basic `tsfel` features can be directly reimplemented as `polars` custom functions (maybe I can optimise this but for now performance is fine), i.e.

```
def var_larger_than_std(x: pl.Series) -> bool:
    """
    Is variance higher than the standard deviation?

    Boolean variable denoting if the variance of x is greater than its standard deviation. Is equal to variance of x
    being larger than 1

    :param x: the time series to calculate the feature of
    :type x: pl.Series
    :return: the value of this feature
    :return type: bool
    """
    y = x.var()
    return y > np.sqrt(y) 

q = (
    dataset.lazy() \
    .groupby_dynamic("ts_local", every="1d", by="id") \
    .agg([
        pl.col("value").count().alias("value__count"),
        var_larger_than_std(pl.col("value")).alias("value__var_larger_than_std"),
        ])
)

q.collect()
```

For basic feature maps `f(series)->series` this works fine. It is quite common though for complex feature maps to produce multiple outputs. For example [fft_coefficient](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/tsfresh/feature_extraction/feature_calculators.html#fft_coefficient) produces multiple outputs. In `tsfel` they're returned as a `dict` and each `key:value` is expanded to into a seperate `pandas.Series` in the final `pandas.Dataframe`.

How can I replicated this in `polars`? Say I have the function

```
def complex_feature(x: pl.Series) -> Dict[str, float]:
    return {"col1":0.0, "col2":1.0}

q = (
    dataset.lazy() \
    .groupby_dynamic("ts_local", every="1d", by="id") \
    .agg([
        complex_feature(pl.col("value")).???,
        ])
)

q.collect()
```

```
┌────────────────────────────────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ ts_local                           ┆ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ --------                           ┆ ---- ┆ ---- │
│ timestamp[ns,tz=Australia/Sydney]  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞════════════════════════════════════╪══════╪══════╡
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2023-01-01                         ┆ 0.0  ┆ 1.0  │
└────────────────────────────────────┴──────┴──────┘
```

i.e. the dict is expaned into seperate columns (it doesn't have to be a dict, I can return a tuple of pl.Series or whatever works)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but calling `unnest` appears to do what I want, i.e.

```
def complex_feature(x: pl.Series) -> Dict[str, float]:
    return {"col1":0.0, "col2":1.0}

q = (
    dataset.lazy() \
    .groupby_dynamic("ts_local", every="1d", by="id") \
    .agg([
        complex_feature(pl.col("value")).alias("value__complex_feature"),
        ])
    .unnest("value__complex_feature")
)

q.collect()
```

It accepts a string or list or strings (I also found references to `unnest_all` but they may be out of date.